# How can I "register" my library libfoo.so to link it with `-lfoo`?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, dynamic-linking

1. How can I "register" my library `foo.c`, compiled to `libfoo.so`, to link it with `-lfoo`? Is it by appending its path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Is it by running `sudo ldconfig`?
2. For curiosity, who do I "register" it with? That is, which application "needs to know" what `-lfoo` means in order for `gcc bar.c -lfoo` to work? Is it the bash environment? Is it gcc? Is it the kernel?
3. Is any of this different for static libraries (eg. `libfoo.a`)?

Comment: Add -L/directory/where/libfooso/sits to the linker command line args

Comment: The application is the linker, normallt called `ld`. You "register" your library with `ld` by placing it in the default search place, usually `/usr/lib`. Otherwise you need to pass a `-L` argument.

Comment: Maybe you consider using [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your library is not in a "*standard*" library directory such as (eg. `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`) then you'll need to tell the compiler it's location `-L` when you link it `-l`:

```
$ gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
        |                                        |
        |__ location of libfoo.so or libfoo.a    |__ link libfoo.so or libfoo.a
```

> GCC assumes that all libraries start with ‘lib’ and end with .so or .a
>   (.so is for shared object or shared libraries, and .a is for archive,
>   or statically linked libraries).

- `-L` is the location to search for libraries linked to your executable
- `-l` links the library to the executable (`-lfoo` can be translated as "link library libfoo.so")

When using shared libraries sometimes simply linking them is not enough (eg. if the library is not installed in a standard location such as the example shown above). This is where using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `rpath` or `ldconfig` comes into play. Static library paths won't need to be set like shared libraries since they are compiled with the executable.

### [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html)

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/foo:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Exporting this variable informs the run-time linker to look in the specified location for the `libfoo.so` library that's associated with the executable. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is more or less a temporary, or convenient way of setting a library's location.

### [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath)

```
$ gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

`rpath` works similarly to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (as libraries can reside almost anywhere in userland), however, `rpath` is linked to the executable at compile time, and sets a "fixed" library location.

### [ldconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

Ultimately what might be the best solution is to use `ldconfig`, which creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the standard library locations and ones you can specify. It does require elevated permissions (eg. `sudo`) to set paths up this way, and should be used with a certain degree of caution.

```
$ sudo cp /home/username/foo/libfoo.so /usr/local/lib
$ sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib/libfoo.so
```

This copies the library into `/usr/local/lib` with permissions set to be readable by everyone.

```
$ sudo ldconfig
$ ldconfig -p | grep foo
libfoo.so (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libfoo.so
```

Then we update the loader cache, and verify the path is set correctly.

```
$ gcc -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

By using `ldconfig`, the `-L` option, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `rpath` now shouldn't be needed.

---

<sub>Additional Information</sub>

↳ [Shared Libraries With GCC on Linux](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)

Comment: Am I missing something, or why would the library be in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: So `ldconfig` is only for libraries in standard locations (eg. `/usr/local/lib`)? (Thanks so much for the answer, btw)

Comment: @étale-cohomology: Sure, you can include additional directories with `ldconfig`, for example (`ldconfig /usr/local/foo`); this would update the cache used by the run-time linker to include your own library path in addition to the standard ones. I would advise using caution though — and not to deviate much from the type of paths it would normally use; I say this only because there is some risk of including directories that are not secure or outside the superuser realm —  (eg. from the ldconfig man page:  `-i Manually link individual libraries. Intended for use by experts only.`).

Comment: I'm a newbie to linking, I don't feel changing the ld cache via ldconfig is advisable; isn't this effectively equivalent to installing your libraries to the system's default path since it effects all dynamically linked software on that system?